# views stripping html tags

Tags: views

I am using views to create a table in which I display blogs title and body. Blog is a content type in which body field can be any of plain text, HTML and full HTML. I want to display only two lines of the body for which I use trim option under Rewrite results tag, and set maximum length to 300 which serves the purpose for paragraphs. But if there is a line break then this doesn't work and the text appears in three lines. Please refer to snapshot below :
[image]

The output in row number 2 is desired one. How do I go about it?

Comment: You can strip our the <br> tag while entering the text in the blog content type. By this way you can avoid the new line in views too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Rewrite results" section, when you checked check-box "Trim this field to a maximum length", there is check-box "Field can contain HTML" in this section. If you check check-box ""Field can contain HTML", then Drupal will maintain your HTML with content.

[image: Trim length]